# Customize logger name of Flask app

Tags: python, logging, flask

I am configuring the handler and formatter for `app.logger`. In the output, the name of the logger is always "flask.app". Is it possible to change the name of the logger?

```
logger1 = RotatingFileHandler('app.log', maxBytes=4096)
logger1.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %message)s")
logger1.setFormatter(formatter)
app.logger.addHandler(logger1)
app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 2):

Flask 1.0 hard coded the name to `flask.app` to simplify configuration. Some customization may be added back in a future version, see [this issue](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2866).

You can subclass and override `Flask.logger` to change what it returns.

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.utils import cached_property

class LoggerFlask(Flask):
    @cached_property
    def logger(self):
        return super().logger.getChild(self.name)
```

Now the logger will be `flask.app.my_app`.

You can also return your own logger without using `super().logger`, but you'll miss out on the automatic configuration that Flask applies. This shouldn't be a problem in your case since you're doing your own configuration.

```
import logging
from flask import Flask
from flask.helpers import locked_cached_property

class LoggerFlask(Flask):
    @locked_cached_property
    def logger(self):
        return logging.getLogger(self.name)
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Flask v1.1.0 the name of the logger will match the app.name. This is the value passed to `Flask(import_name)`.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask('CoolApp')
```